# How to delete a file after installation is over in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am developing a windows application in .NET Framework using c#. I want to run two exe files at the time of installation of my application, one after the other, in a specific order.

I know that I can run an exe at the time of installation, by using the custom action, but I don't know how to run it in a specific order.

I am new to c#, so a detailed walk through is prefered.

Comment: I guess you are using the Visual Studio installer since you write about a custom action? Is this correct? (In other case please state what installer technology you are using.)

Comment: Maybe [Sequencing Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helps...

Comment: I am using VS 2008 for creating the setup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Custom action you can perform the same, you need to use "Commit" option of custom action for this