# how to delete a file after windows installer installation is complete?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a file after installation is over in c# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342851/how-to-delete-a-file-after-installation-is-over-in-c)

I am developing a windows application using .NET Framework 3.5, using c#. I am making an windows installer using visual studio 2008. During installation i am running an .EXE file for some purpose by adding a custom action in the commit phase of installation. And its working fine, except that its placing the .EXE file in the installation folder after insatallation.

But I want to delete the .EXE file after installation is complete, but I am unable to find out how to do so. Please help me out !

Thanks,

Bibhu

Comment: @Jeff Sheldon - that question was asked by me only. but this is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use post-build event? Might this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could [add a `CustomAction` project to your solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and run that after running the `.EXE` file, deleting the `.EXE` file on `Commit`.

Comment: sorry i am unable to get you. I have added a custom Action to run the exe file  and now after completion of its work i want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a batch file to delete this file after some time. Start that batch file as new process just before closing your exe.
keep this batch file in temp folder so that even if you don't delete its ok.
You can write to delete that batchfile in that batch file only.(it works)

through your exe create a file xyz.bat as text file.
In that write

```
del <YourExePath> 
del <BatchFilePath>
```

Execute this as a new process

Comment: but its not allowing me to attach a batch file in the installer. How to do that, can you show me a walkthrough of that.

Comment: through your exe create a file xyz.bat as text file. In that write `del <your EXE path> del <Batch file path>` Execute this as a new process

Comment: Thanks I will surely try it out. :)